# Mongod on digitalocean ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

I have an application running on a digitalocean droplet (ubuntu 16.04).

I have installed mongodb and used monogrestore to get my db on the server.

I have a firewall with http, https, OpenSSH, my_local_ip, my_droplet_ip, 127.0.0.1 all to port 27017.

mongod is active and running

mongodb is not running

I get a 503 error (timeout) when trying to access the web pages with the database articles on it.

Do I need to have both mongod and mongodb active and running to make the connection? and if so does one run on port 27017 and the other on 27018?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `mongod` is the server daemon for your MongoDB deployment (listening on localhost port 27017 by default); there is no additional `mongodb` service to run. The 503 timeout is related to accessing your web application over http/https and not specific to MongoDB. This error suggests that you are able to connect to a web server but something isn't configured correctly to host your application. Troubleshooting questions for your web server configuration are probably better asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: thanks Stennie I ended up just running mongodb on a different private server and adding my login in the uri. Honestly, I think my problem was that I was not binding the ip to localhost(0.0.0.0). Thank you for replying and the server fault rec.